# SwiftData Predicate ridiculous set-contains-check crash in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-data

It is so ridiculous, but I have a crash in this code:

```swift
var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<FactModel>()
fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 10
fetchDescriptor.sortBy = [.init(\.showCount, order: .forward)]
let key = category.key
if key != "general" {
    fetchDescriptor.predicate = #Predicate { fact in
        fact.categories.contains(key)
    }
}
        
let result = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
```

The crash happens on the fetching when the predicate is active. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

If I change the predicate, all works well. But the problems are only if I use my `Set<String>` with `.contains`.

```
fetchDescriptor.predicate = #Predicate { fact in
    fact.text.contains("a")
}
```

Please help me understand the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fact.categories.contains(category)`?

Comment: no. categories is Set<String>. Key is String

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: Is there a message in console when it crashes? Could it be linked to https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/using-structs-and-enums-in-swiftdata-models ?

Comment: console is empty. Just the error

Comment: The reason is what @Larme linked to that you can't use a property that is a collection in a predicate. I change from `contains` to `contains(where:)` and then got the error message `Can't have a non-relationship collection element in a subquery` in the console